# Polynomial solvability

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem:

Min$_{x}$ $\qquad  \sum_{(i,j,t,s)\in I_r}||x_ix_j-x_tx_s||^2$

S.t.: $\qquad  x\in \mathcal{C} ;$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$
and $\quad x_j\geq 0\;\;  j=1,2,...,n$

Here, $\mathcal{C}$ is a convex set and $I_r$ is a polynomial sized index set.

Can this problem be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: "$I_r$ is a polynomial sized index set." Polynomial-sized in $n$?

Comment: Yes, polynomial-sized in $n$.

Comment: This question is virtually the same as http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5279/276. Please do not post multiple questions that are virtually identical; it is considered poor etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $I_r = \{(1, 2, 3, 4)\}$, and let $F(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} = \|x_{1}x_{2} - x_{3}x_{4}\|^2$. Consider the points $(1, 3, 0, 0)$ and $(3, 1, 0, 0)$; their midpoint is $(2, 2, 0, 0)$. If $F$ were convex, then it would be true that

\begin{align}
F(2, 2, 0, 0) \leq \frac{1}{2}F(1, 3, 0, 0) + \frac{1}{2}F(1, 3, 0, 0).
\end{align}

However,

\begin{align}
16 \not\leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 9 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 9.
\end{align}

In general, nonconvex problems are $\mathcal{NP}$-hard.

Comment: Note the similarity to my answer to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/convexity-of-a-function.